# super() in constructor

Tags: java, constructor, super

I'm reading through some code. In the constructor it has super() but the class implements interface which of course doesn't have  a constructor. So which super() it is referring to?

```
public class BoundingBox implements IBoundingVolume {

public BoundingBox() {
        super();
        mTransformedMin = new Number3D();
        mTransformedMax = new Number3D();
        mTmpMin = new Number3D();
        mTmpMax = new Number3D();
        mPoints = new Number3D[8];
        mTmp = new Number3D[8];
        mMin = new Number3D();
        mMax = new Number3D();
        for(int i=0; i<8; ++i) {
            mPoints[i] = new Number3D();
            mTmp[i] = new Number3D();
        }
}


public interface IBoundingVolume {
    public void calculateBounds(Geometry3D geometry);
    public void drawBoundingVolume(Camera camera, float[] projMatrix, float[] vMatrix, float[] mMatrix);
    public void transform(float[] matrix);
    public boolean intersectsWith(IBoundingVolume boundingVolume);
    public BaseObject3D getVisual();
}
```

Comment: It is calling to the constructor of superclass. In this case - Object.

Comment: It refers to Object class.

Comment: It calls java.lang.Object constructor i suppose.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`super()` refers to the extended `class` (not an implemented interface). Which in this case is `Object`

So it will call the constructor in `Object` (Which does nothing)

Comment: In Java all classes are derived from Object, unless they are derived from another class. Therefore, super() refers to the constructor of the Object class.

Comment: Actually *ALL* Java classes are derived from Object. If they extend another class it just means they have a larger hierarchy.

Comment: hmmm, why would anyone refer to Object()'s constructor? if I delete this line with super() it won't have any effect will it?

Comment: Its a redundant line, as it is implied anyway. If you remove that line it will still call the super classes constructor. This ensures all constructors in the hierarchy are called

Comment: See the note at the bottom of this page: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: I also ran across super() in constructor(s) of class(es) inheriting directly from Object - does it make any sense to keep it? Or could I freely remove it for the sake of readability?

Comment: Should be safe to remove. Note: it is called implicitly anyway if you do remove it.

Comment: If it does nothing then why eclipse auto generates `super()` while generating constructor even I am not using any inheritance. I think it does not make any sense using `super()`  in constructor.

Answer (score 19):

Super is referencing to the extended class. By default it is the Object class. The constructor in Object does nothing. In other words you can delete this line as it is not necessary.

Please also note what Oracle is saying about this topic:

> If a constructor does not explicitly invoke a superclass constructor, the Java compiler automatically inserts a call to the no-argument constructor of the superclass. If the super class does not have a no-argument constructor, you will get a compile-time error. Object does have such a constructor, so if Object is the only superclass, there is no problem.

Source: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Answer (score 4):

`super` calls the constructor of the extended class. All classes in Java derive from `Object`. Additionally, if the author of a class doesn't create a constructor for the class, a default constructor is created that does nothing.

In your case, `super` is calling the default constructor of `Object`.

If you'd like to learn more about `Object`, you can read the source code of `Object.java` [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/lang/Object.java.html).

Answer (score -1):

Now let me tell you the real reason why we use super() here that is if we want to call directly super-class constructor . when we call constructor then many constructor may be invoked in hierarchy,so to eliminate that we can use super().
During test-cases you might deal with 
"Do not provide any additional constructor other than what is asked in the problem statement"
so, The solution is use Super() in your constructor.

Comment: The OP would appear to be aware what `super()` does. Your answer does not address the `interface` aspect.