# Overriding GroupLayout constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor, grouplayout

Why can't I add a constructor in class `GroupLayout` like:

```
public class xxx extends GroupLayout {

  public xxx(Container host, String...arg) {
    //code
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`GroupLayout` doesn't have a no-argument constructor meaning Java can't make an implicit call to it's constructor, so you'd be getting a compile-time error about that. You just need to call `super(host)` as the first line of your method to invoke the constructor that `GroupLayout` does have. Try:

```
public class SubGroupLayout extends GroupLayout {

    public SubGroupLayout(Container host, String ...arg) {
        super(host);
        // then, do your own code here
    }
}
```

See [Using the Keyword super](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html) and [super() in constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15206890/super-in-constructor) for more details.